# match column names using re.compile with or operator

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of columns names and I built def function to match columns names with prefix xrf and suffix ppm but the result comes only with the (xrf_.**pc),would you please help to get names (xrf*.**pc) and (xrf*.*_ppm).

code

````
def xrf_minerals_columns(xrf_samples):
       # xrf_columns=xrf_samples.columns.tolist()
       r1 = re.compile("xrf_.*_pc") or  re.compile("xrf_.*_ppm")
       minerals_percentage_columns=list(filter(r1.match, xrf_samples))
       return minerals_percentage_columns
minerals_percentage_columns=xrf_minerals_columns(xrf_samples)
print (minerals_percentage_columns)```
````

Comment: what do you think `r1 = re.compile("xrf_.*_pc") or  re.compile("xrf_.*_ppm")` does? because I don't think it does what you think it does, `or` returns the first truthy value, meaning that `r1` in this configuration will always be what `re.compile('xrf_.*_pc')` returns (because it returns a truthy object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not match your requirement. If you want to

> match columns names with prefix xrf and suffix ppm

just this much is enough

```
r1 = re.compile("xrf_.*_ppm")
```

but I think what you want is, to match prefix `xrf_` and suffix either `_ppm` or `_pc`

in that case you can use

```
r1 = re.compile("xrf_.*_p(c|pm)")
```

If you are wondering what's wrong with your code, let's print your r1

```
>>> r1 = re.compile("xrf_.*_pc") or  re.compile("xrf_.*_ppm")
>>> print(r1)
re.compile('xrf_.*_pc')
```

see [Null_coalescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator)